# Same certificate for encryption for different To:-addresses

Tags: microsoft-outlook, certificate, encryption, exchange-2013

When I write a mail and click on encrypt in message options, how can I tell outlook to use the same certificate when writing to two different mail addresses of the same person?

In my case, the person I write two has two different mail addresses configured in Exchange O365. However, sending encrypted mails only works with one address.

This becomes an issue if you have a lot of people with multiple mail addresses and you always have to know which is the one that works with encryption...

edit: I know how to make a PEM-certificate using OpenSSL for two mail addresses where the other one goes to the subjectAlternativeName-Field. However, Outlook or Exchange don't seem to mind this, it has absolutely no effect. The only other option currently known (it's called 'proper solution' in the comments below) is having a separate certificate for each mail address.

Is there a way to tell Outlook/Exchange/whoever looks at the certificate that there is another mail address this is issued to in some extension section?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are issued with the e-mail address in them already. You can't automatically send to e-mail addresses that do not appear in the certificate. Without seeing the details, I'm fairly sure the certificate only has the one e-mail address and therein lies your problem.

Comment: Suppose I make a certificate with two mail addresses, IIRC the other one goes to the subjectAlternativeName-Field. How do I tell Exchange to mind this? Everything I tried had no effect. Any experience?

Comment: @sinned - Each address would need its own certificate.  We are dealing with PGP right?

Comment: @Ramhound Is having two certificates (one for each address) the only solution? This would mean there is no way to tell Outlook to mind the subjectAlternativeName-Field. We use PEM as a certificate format.

Comment: @sinned - Update your question with this information.  How different are the emails?  The proper solution is each email would have its own certificate.